# csurf node : csrf token used many times with no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, csrf

i have written a project and it's near it's production phase and i  accidentally found a bug in my code

my project has a page in which i have many form which i use ajax to post them and i found that i'm not updating the csrf token for every ajax request and my csurf-npm module is not throwing any errors.

my project is so so big that i can't write it here but the only places i'm using it are :

```
var csrfProtection = require("csurf")({cookie: true});
```

in my routers:

```
router.post(csrfProtection(),/*some BILIBILI function*/);
```

and i'm sending this to the page where i post my forms with ajax:

```
req.csrfToken();
```

can you guys help me figure out what's going on.

thank you

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, the token can be unique for the session. see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens

Comment: @GabrielBleu thanks man , i thought it is some how recreated whenever you use req.csrfToken()  (which will give another csrfToken even if your session didn't change)i thought it's implemented the way that it has a key which is saved in session and it will be used to decrypt the token and is recreated any time you call for it

Comment: how can i mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem, the token can be unique for the session. see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens